# Harmon.ie displays a hidden sharepoint column when viewing/editing properties of document/message

Tags: harmon.ie

In Sharepoint, we have a hidden column in the view of an document library ([Image of content type column setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84kBm.png)). When the user connects to that document library with Harmon.ie, it displays the hidden column when viewing/editing properties of document/message. When I go to that document library in SharePoint the column is correctly hidden. This behavior is tested with versions Enterprise Edition Version 5.1.0.8306 and also version 5.7.1.1167.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you hide the column with the help of PowerShell script. Here below a sample of such script (to run on SharePoint server side)

```
#Get the web and site column objects
$web = Get-SPWeb http://portal
$column = $web.Fields["Test Column"]
#Change the ShowInEditForm and other properties and update objects
$column.ShowInEditForm = $false
$column.ShowInNewForm = $false
$column.ShowInDisplayForm = $true
£column.ShowInViewForms = $true
$column.Update()
$web.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: It's SharePoint online... and in SharePoint the column is hidden ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the column in web interface also work in harmon.ie

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download and install http sniffer like Fiddler. Indeed on my side a hidden column is honored with harmon.ie and SharePoint online.
As a client application harmon.ie calls valid and standard web services to connect SharePoint.
Make sure with Fiddler that the column returned in SharePoint schema is indeed marked as indeed (see my below answer for column "Account Name")

I also suggest you download and install latest version 6.0 from harmon.ie site.

```html
POST https://ravenwooddemo.sharepoint.com/sandbox/_vti_bin/lists.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: harmon.ie 6.0.0.41373
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListContentType"

No hidden
<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Account Name" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="harmonie custom columns" ID="{ae591ade-2902-44ea-9bbf-80902d74f6d6}" SourceID="{79bb1ae3-c801-4c46-93fc-7a9cb4ef5dda}" StaticName="Account_x0020_Name" Name="Account_x0020_Name" Version="5" Customization="" ColName="nvarchar14" RowOrdinal="0" Hidden="FALSE" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node=""><Default>CocaCola</Default></Field>


Hidden
<Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Account Name" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Group="harmonie custom columns" ID="{ae591ade-2902-44ea-9bbf-80902d74f6d6}" SourceID="{79bb1ae3-c801-4c46-93fc-7a9cb4ef5dda}" StaticName="Account_x0020_Name" Name="Account_x0020_Name" Version="5" Customization="" ColName="nvarchar14" RowOrdinal="0" Hidden="TRUE" ReadOnly="FALSE" PITarget="" PrimaryPITarget="" PIAttribute="" PrimaryPIAttribute="" Aggregation="" Node=""><Default>CocaCola</Default></Field>here
```